# A field with big array on mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, performance, mongoose, gridfs

I am a beginner at Mongo and I made a data base with the following topology.

Some fields of metadata and one field that contain the experiment results.
experiment results- vector of integers with ~150,000 values

```
status = db.DataTest.insert_one(
    {
        "person_num" : num,
        "life_cycle" : cycle,
        "other_metadata" : meta_data,
        "results_of_experiment": big_array
    }
)
```

I inserted something like 7500 of those documents
Its occupied 8GB of memory and work really slowly for find operations.

**I don't need those experiment results to search by them** only the option to retrieve them from the DB as chunk of data.
Is there another solution to store on the DB the experiment results?
Is using "gridfs" is relevant to this case and not too complicated?

Comment: How big is the "big_array"? Slow `find` operation is most likely because your `find` operations are not indexed properly. What are the most common `find` operation you're doing?

Comment: The big_array is 150000 integers values so something like 0.6MB.
And I do find operation only on the other fields e.g 
'db.DataTest.find( { "life_cycle": { $gt: 800 } }).limit(5)'

Comment: How about "What are the most common find operation you're doing"?

Comment: <pre> <code> db.DataTest.find( { "life_cycle": { $gt: 800 } }).limit(5) <code>

Comment: Do you have an index on the `life_cycle` field? How about the other fields, do you use them often in any of your queries?

Comment: No I don't have but its not doing it automatically? If I preform the exact query twice at the second time its should be faster? not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, the most common query is

```
db.DataTest.find( { "life_cycle": { $gt: 800 } }).limit(5)
```

Without an index on the `life_cycle` field, MongoDB is forced to do a collection scan. That is, fetch & evaluate all documents in your collection one by one. In a large collection, this will take a long time.

MongoDB does *not* create indexes automatically. You would have to observe your most common queries, and create indexes to support those queries. As far as I know, there is no automatic index creation in any database software; SQL, NoSQL, or otherwise.

Database indexing is a deep subject and cannot be explained in a short answer.

Having said that, if you create an index on the `life_cycle` field, it should improve your query times **but only for the query you posted above**. Other query types would likely require different indexes. You can do so in the `mongo` shell:

```
db.DataTest.createIndex({life_cycle: 1})
```

I encourage you to read these pages to understand more about indexing in MongoDB:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/